# Getting table row to span entire width

Tags: html, css

I am simply trying to get my table row to go all the way across the table, but it is only filling about 20% on the left side.

```
<table id="t1" style="width:25%; height:50%">
<tr id="tr1">
  <td id="user1"></td>
  <td id="champ1"></td>
  <td id="wr1"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I put values in the data cells in a script later on. 
Here is the CSS.

```
#t1 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
tr {
  width: 100%;
  align-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Why are your <td> elements closed with </tr>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you don't close the `<td>`'s, you have each  terminated in a closing `</tr>` instead. If there is no content in the `<td>`, add a `&nbsp;`

The table rows (`<tr>`) will default to 100% of table if remove the `display: inline-block`, and terminate them correctly. The wrap them in something to make them float.  This allows you opportunity to do a caption for the table or add controls.

I'd suggest the html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <table id="table1">
     <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
   <table id="table2">
     <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
/* Optionally throw in a media query, so the floats only happen if there is enough room for the two tables next to each other, but seamlessly fall under each other if not -- @media screen and (min-width: 600px){*/
.left{float:left; width:50%;}
.right{float:right; width:50%;}
/* } Optionally, close the media query here. */
/* Keep the wrapper open until both tables are done*/
.wrapper:after{clear:both;} 
table{}
/* Add margin if the tables get to close, or negative margin if you want them closer*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `display: inline-block` from the #t1 style.

This will also cause the table to center because of the auto margins, so remove these if you want the table left-aligned.

Example JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lrog2pgm/

Comment: The only problem with that is that I have another table and I want the two of them to be next to each other.

Comment: Use float:left and float:right to get them side by side.

Comment: Ahhhh that worked. I don't want them so far apart though, so I guess I'll just add margins?

Comment: Wrap them in a div that's the total width you want. Also, like Mark said on your original post, your td's are closed with tr's. Eg: http://jsfiddle.net/Lrog2pgm/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is a mess...

First, you are closing `<td>` with `</tr>`.

I have no idea what `align-content: center;` is?  I think you mean `text-align: center;`.

You are sharing an `#id` on 2 selectors (id='tr1').  Not allowed.

Try fixing up some of that stuff first.

Comment: The question has IDs tr1 and t1. They're not duplicates. Also, have a look at align-content: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_align-content&preval=center

Comment: Oh... my bad.  I see that now.  Might want to reconsider your naming convention then...  this is very vague, and obviously easily mistakable.  Also, you really should be using classes instead of IDs.  Better for reusability and scaling.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is a mess. It has mismatching tags and is just disorganized all together. Second of all, never use tables again. They are virtually deprecated. Everything you do with a table can be done with list these days. Tables are not even responsive. And just like you've discovered, they are temperamental. My answer: Use a `<ul>`

Comment: Tables are alive and well. They are not intended to be used for layout purposes, but are perfectly valid for tabular data: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html.  The question did not indicate what the table is being used for so it may be the semantically correct markup.